# AngularJS custom form controls validation

Tags: angularjs, contenteditable, angularjs-forms

I'm having issues with validating custom form controls in AngularJS.

The two issues are:

1. I want to trigger a custom error when the placeholder/initial text has not been modified within the content editable field. I've tried various approaches -- but with no luck (including trying to edit `$isValid`).
2. *Solved:* I can't seem to trigger the `ng-show` on the error messages to make them appear when `ng-minlength`, `ng-maxlength`, and `ng-required` are invalid. ( *Answer:* I didn't have a name attr on the div)

Please see the Plnkr below, and code samples:

https://plnkr.co/edit/Up6Q4D7cMDQQxCodLrpE?p=preview

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example - example-example40-production</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="form-example2">
    <form name="myForm">
        <div contentEditable="true" ng-model="standfirst" title="Click to edit" ng-required="true" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="20">Some People</div>
        <p ng-show="myForm.standfirst.$error.required" class="text-danger">You did not enter a standfirst</p>
        <p ng-show="myForm.standfirst.$error.minlength" class="text-danger">Your standfirst is too short</p>
        <p ng-show="myForm.standfirst.$error.maxlength" class="text-danger">Your standfirst is too long</p>
    </form>
    <pre>model = {{content}}</pre>

    <style type="text/css">
        div[contentEditable] {
            cursor: pointer;
            background-color: #D0D0D0;
        }
    </style>
</body>

</html>
```

```
(function(angular) {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('form-example2', []).directive('contenteditable', function() {
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
                // view -> model
                elm.on('blur', function() {
                    ctrl.$setViewValue(elm.html());
                });

                // model -> view
                ctrl.$render = function() {
                    elm.html(ctrl.$viewValue);
                };

                // load init value from DOM
                ctrl.$setViewValue(elm.html());
            }
        };
    });
})(window.angular);
```

Comment: You don't have an input named `standfirst` anywhere on the form.

Comment: Also, what is this directive supposed to be doing?  It's not really clear.

Comment: @ryanyuyu the directive was just boilerplate from an example of custom form components in the angular documentation. I've amended my question after your comments

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$pristine` to check if input value is changed.

```
<p ng-show="myForm.standfirst.$pristine" class="text-danger">Your start error message</p>
```

Because you set a value at startup in your directive you have to reset the form. To do so add `ctrl.$setPristine()` to your code

```
// load init value from DOM
ctrl.$setViewValue(elm.html());
ctrl.$setPristine();
```

Comment: Then I would use the `$pristine` check on the `ng-disabled` of the submit button? To prevent an invalid submission..

Comment: You can use `$valid` to prevent an invalid submission. But to prevent an unchanged submit you can use `$pristine`. I always make the check inside the `ng-disable` attribute, but you can do it inside the submit function as well.